# Change image instantly when user enter any input in textfield

Tags: ios7

I have tried this in button action. But my requirement is to change image without button action.

```
if (self.MyTextField.text.length!=0)
{
    self.MyImageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"redImage"];
}    
else
{
    self.MyImageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"greenImage"];
}
```

please help me..

Comment: I understand this is a continuation of your previous question. Would you mind giving some context here to make this a standalone question? Everybody may not have seen your previous one.

Comment: If you want to change image as soon as user start editing text field, then you must write this code in UITextField delegate method textFieldDidBeginEditing.

Comment: i added this code to textFieldDidBeginEditing. but its not changing image..

Answer (score 1):

**First include the following protocol:**

```
@interface ViewController ()<UITextFieldDelegate>
```

**Next set the textField's delegate to the viewController where you will write the code**

**Then implement the following method:**

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if (textField.text.length!=0) {
        self.MyImageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"redImage"];
    }
    else {
        self.MyImageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"greenImage"];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign a selector for your `UITextfiled` like this   `[textField addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];`
And in your method u can change the image like below

```
-(void)textFieldDidChange:(UITextField *)textField
{
 if (textField.text.length!=0)
  {
    self.MyImageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"redImage"];
  }    
  else
  {
    self.MyImageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"greenImage"];
  }
}
```